# Wildfly Swarm Logging ignores Debug

Tags: logging, yaml, config, wildfly-swarm

I configurated my Wildfly-Swarm Logging using the `project-defaults.yml`.
The Logging works well in regards to File-output and Pattern.
However, the Log-level gets ignored and is set to INFO all the time.
I went with the "explanation" on https://reference.wildfly-swarm.io/fractions/logging.html however it's not working.

My `project-defaults.yml` is

```
swarm:
  logging:
    pattern-formatters:
      NORMAL:
        pattern: "%p [%c] %s%e%n"
      EXCEPTION:
        pattern: "%p [%c.%m] %s%e%n"
    periodic-rotating-file-handlers:
      DEBUGLOG:
        file:
          path: logs/shaker.log
        suffix: .yyyy-MM-dd
        named-formatter: NORMAL
        level: DEBUG
      EXCEPTIONLOG:
        file:
          path: logs/exception.log
        suffix: .yyyy-MM-dd
        named-formatter: EXCEPTION
        level: WARN
    root-logger:
      handlers:
      - CONSOLE
      - DEBUGLOG
      - EXCEPTIONLOG
```

In both log-files and in the console the log is set to INFO.
I've tried adding

```
logging:
    loggers:
      de.mypackage:
        level: DEBUG
```

But it only changes the log level of console.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it turns out I've misspelled `de.mypackage`.
Setting

```
logging:
  loggers:
    de.mypackage:
      level: DEBUG
```

sets the level to DEBUG in all logs under `de.mypackage`.